# React states seem to be updating one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having trouble with the useEffect hook in React, and am using it to add a row of data to a table. It seems to be triggering when I want it to (after I change the state of "count" by clicking a button), and it seems to be adding the right row of data to the table (i.e. the "adding row" log statement shows the data I'd expect.

However, after newRow is set and setTableData is fed this new row, the following console.log statement shows the previous row from the table. This causes the table to seemingly display one row behind what it should be, i.e. when I expect to see row 5 added to the table, row 4 is added instead, and row 5 isn't added til I expect row 6 to be. I saw a few similar questions and tried the fixes there, but couldn't seem to get it to work. What am I missing?

```
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);  
const [newRow, setNewRow] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      console.log("adding row", count, data[0][count]);
      let yearTeam = "";
      if (!data[0][count].team) {
        yearTeam = "Total";
      } else {
        yearTeam = teamAbbreviator(data[0][count].team.name);
      }
      if (count < data[0].length) {
        setNewRow({
          year: data[0][count].season,
          team: yearTeam,
          hits: data[0][count].stat.hits,
          hrs: data[0][count].stat.homeRuns,
        });
        setTableData([...tableData, newRow]);
        console.log("new row is set to ", newRow);
      } else {

      }
    }
  }, [count]);
```

Comment: `console.log("new row is set to ", newRow);` This logs out the `newRow` from the current render, not the next render. Calling `setNewRow` just asks react to render the component again, it doesn't change the value in the local const `newRow`.

Comment: So if we have: 

Render 1 (triggered by 'count' variable changing from button click):
Let's say newRow's value upon the first rendering is row1Data.
I then call setNewRow(row2Data).
If I console.log(newRow), if I understand correctly, I will still see row1Data logged. 

When Render 2 ('count' variable changes upon button click again) occurs, then I will see row2Data. I guess my question then is, how do I render to see row2's data without clicking the button for 'count' again? I've tried something like the following - useEffect(() => {console.log(tableData)}, [tableData]) to no avail.

Comment: When you call `setTableData([...tableData, newRow]);`, are you wanting `newRow` to be the object you just created on the previous line? If so, assign that object to a variable and use it. Eg: `const temp = { year: data[0][count].season, /* etc */}; setNewRow(temp); setTableData([...tableData, temp]); console.log(temp)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I realize now I was unnecessarily making row a state variable.